# Regex for searching strings matching the following one

Tags: regex, string, search

I am searching strings matching the following one in my source code:

```
<CONSTANT_STRING_1> <CONSTANT_STRING_2> <VARIABLE_DIGITS> <CONSTANT_STRING_3>
```

where

`<CONSTANT_STRING_1>`, `<CONSTANT_STRING_2>` and `<CONSTANT_STRING_3>` are constant strings like "ABC", ""DEF" and "GHI".

`<VARIABLE_DIGITS>` is a random number of 14 digits like "12345678901234"

Note: there are white spaces between words.

What I am looking for is to search `<CONSTANT_STRING_1> <CONSTANT_STRING_2> <WHATEVER> <CONSTANT_STRING_3>`. How can I build the Regex?

Comment: you mean this `<CONSTANT_STRING_1> <CONSTANT_STRING_2> \d{14} <CONSTANT_STRING_3>` ?

Comment: @Avinash Raj - Yes! Post the answer and I will accept it as the solution to my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below regex.

```
<CONSTANT_STRING_1> <CONSTANT_STRING_2> \d{14} <CONSTANT_STRING_3>
```

Where, `\d{14}` matches exactly the 14 digit number.

Answer (score 2):

I am reading that by "constant string" you mean character strings? If so the below should work to find that full string you are looking for. Btw the website linked below is really great for visualizing this type of problem... give it a try :)

```
(([a-zA-Z]+\s){2})[0-9]{14}\s([a-zA-Z]+)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/a1bTTN4SoWQjW2ci)

To break it down...

`(([a-zA-Z]+\s){2})` means a string of one or more characters comprised of either LC or UC letters followed by a space and that whole thing (chars + space) repeated twice

`[0-9]{14}\s` 14 digits followed by a space. As @Avinash said \d{14}\s is another way of writing this portion

`([a-zA-Z]+)$` Another string of one or more characters. The $ indicates that this ends the string you are searching for